# Function wont run all lines

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the bellow function but it seems to not get passed the if let snapshotValue line I believe its because snapshotUrl.value is not a dictionary. If so How do I convert it to one?

```
func fetchAllPostImages() {
    print("fetchAllPostImages function")
    self.ref.child("Posts").child(self.userID).child(self.postNum).child("Images").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        var snapshotUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ImageUrl")
        var snapshotTimeStamp = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "timeStamp")
        print("fhdsjaklhfkjdsfksahdjksfjlashfkljdhs")
        print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ImageUrl"))
        print(snapshotUrl.value, "value")

        if let snapShotValue = snapshotUrl.value as? [String: String] {
            print("jkdfbhksafgsaghsjbbvcbcbcbccbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")

            for (_, value) in snapShotValue {
                print(value)

                if let imageURL = URL(string: value) {
                    print(imageURL, "image url here")

                    do {
                        let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageAsData)
                        //                                let ImageObject = Media()
                        //                                ImageObject.image = image
                        var timeStamp = 0.0
                        self.arrayOfImgObj.append(Media(image: image!, timeStamp: timeStamp))
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        print(self.arrayOfImgObj.count, "array.count")
                    } catch {
                        print("imageURL was not able to be converted into data")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Output of the func:

```
fetchAllPostImages function 
fhdsjaklhfkjdsfksahdjksfjlashfkljdhs 
Snap (ImageUrl)
     https://firebasestge.googleapis.com/v0/b/copyyubidatabase.appspot.com/o/rVNvbWrC9aarXOTSHNXGoaIeR5B3%2Fpost:563592299%2Fimage1?alt=media&token=a0c4aeda-769a-48ac-85c8-ab595ccfdf08
     Optional(https://fireestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/copyyubidatabase.appspot.com/o/rVNvbWrC9aarXOTSHNXGoaIeR5B3%2Fpost:563592299%2Fimage1?alt=media&token=a0c4aeda-769a-48ac-85c8-ab595ccfdf08)
     value
```

Comment: You should share `snapshotUrl.value`. Without seeing `snapshotUrl.value` how you would expect someone would be able to help you.

Comment: @Satish I added above

Comment: Aaaahhh. My eyes

Comment: @canister_exister?

Comment: @canister_exister fixed

Comment: make print(snapshotUrl.value as? [String: String])

Comment: nil is hwat u get

Comment: because you can't create [string:string] from snapshotUrl.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like snapshotUrl.value is an Optional-wrapped URL.  If you want to convert it to a Dictionary you just need a key and a value.

We don't have access to the data structure of `snapshot` to tell you how to use it exactly.

Here is some playground code that demonstrates what I mean.  This works as-is:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct SnapShot {
    func childSnapshot(forPath: String) -> URLWrapper? {
        return URLWrapper(url: URL(string: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-red-square-grunge-stamp-260nw-338250266.jpg")!)
    }
}

struct URLWrapper {
    var url:URL

    var value:String? {
        get {
            return url.absoluteString
        }
    }
}

func fetchAllPostImages() {
    let session = URLSession.shared

    print("fetchAllPostImages function")
    let snapshot = SnapShot()
    if let snapshotUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ImageUrl"), let snapShotValue = snapshotUrl.value, let imageURL = URL(string: snapShotValue) {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: imageURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                print(image ?? "none")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

fetchAllPostImages()
```

Comment: So i think it worked i get this when i print snapshotValue: ["ImageUrl": https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/copyyubidatabase.appspot.com/o/rVNvbWrC9aarXOTSHNXGoaIeR5B3%2Fpost:563592299%2Fimage1?alt=media&token=a0c4aeda-769a-ac-85c8-ab595ccfdf08]
So how do I then convert this into a string on its onw so i can then convert to URl

Comment: What is your data source?  It seems to me that you are probably going about this wrong.  You should be using an asynchronous model -- URLSession.dataTaskWithRequest()  or URLSession.downloadTaskWithRequest() is the right way to go about fetching multiple images over the network.

Comment: Could you show in your answer how to do what you are saying?

Comment: I get Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'DataSnapshot' on the 4th line

Comment: I moved some of teh continues if let lines and seperated them and now it wont go past the session.dataTask line

Comment: ? have you seen my comments?

Comment: Sound like you have a basic compilation problem.  Try to understand the solution and not just paste it into your project.  You need to understand your data structures and how they are used.